# Prove that for a domain $A$, $A^n$ cannot have $A^m$ as a subring where $m>n$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have to prove that for a domain $A$, $A^n$ cannot have (an isomorphic copy of) $A^m$ as a subring where $m>n$.

My attempt is as follows:

If we let $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a basis for $A^n$ and $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$ be a basis for $A^m$, then we can write
$$a_j=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^jb_i$$
Showing that we cannot have such a basis $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$ comes down to showing that the $a_i$ cannot be independent, so showing that there are $d_i$ not all $0$ s.t.
$$\sum_{j=1}^md_ja_j=0=\sum_{j=1}^md_j\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^jb_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[\sum_{j=1}^md_jc_i^j\right]b_i$$
this last sum is zero iff for all $i:$
$$\sum_{j=1}^md_jc_i^j=0$$
So we want to show that there must a non-trivial solution to the system
$$\begin{align}
d_1c_1^1+\dots+d_mc_1^m&=0\\
\vdots\\
d_1c_n^1+\dots+d_mc_n^m&=0\\
\end{align}$$
But I don't see why this is true.

Comment: Solution [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/2510/450).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure, user2520938